# Rails 3.2 assets:precompile Permission denied 123

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, assets, precompile

I'm trying to precompile my rails app but get this weird error that I don't know how to follow?

rake assets:precompile --trace

```
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Permission denied - /123
/Users/philip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your app on `/123/` which is likely a protected directory. You should really be creating your apps within your home folder.

However, if you want to force `/123` then you can run `sudo rake assets:precompile` and it will work.

Comment: I am at my root app directory when I try to precompile?